# Firebug issue with console.log

Tags: logging, firebug

I have this in my code:

```
console.log("hi there");
```

When I run it in the browser, I get this error:

> Warning: log() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in
>   /home/(etc.)

According to [This page](http://getfirebug.com/logging) I'm doing it right.

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting that error?

Comment: Have you manipulated the console object at all? Or loaded any plugins that may?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but this is running inside of a WordPress installation with a bunch of plugins, is there some way to find out if it's been manipulated?

Comment: `alert(console.log)` and see if it seems appropriate.  It should say something about native code.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm doing this in PHP. I tried `echo console.log;` but that just showed "consolelog", lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message hints that it is coming from PHP, while Firebug's `console` object is only available in JavaScript, i.e. on the client side.
So the `console.log()` within your PHP code is not the same as the one described on getfirebug.com.

You should have a look at the Firebug extension [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), which allows you to debug PHP applications.
And you should also read through the [debugging features available in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare this new function in your code:

```
function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) 
{
    $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) . ');';

    if ($with_script_tags) 
    {
        $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
    }

    echo $js_code;
}
```

Then, you can call the function:

```
$myMessage = "hi there";
console_log($myMessage);
```